# How to deploy an asp.net mvc 4 application with database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, amazon-ec2

I'm new to `asp.net` and want to do the following:

I have an `asp.net mvc 4` website that uses a local database (mdf).
I want to install that website on a windows 2012 server (amazon ec2).

My Questions:

- How do I handle the database?
- How do I move it onto the server?

Answer (score 1):

There are  several steps:

- According to Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410407(v=vs.90).aspx), you should publish first your website to a local folder; you can embark your database by clicking `Include files from the App_Data folder`.
- You will transfer your published folder to your Windows 2012 in, for example, a subfolder of `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`.
- You will have to create a new Web Site in IIS (I'll let you search by yourself ;-) )

Note: I am not that familiar with `mdf` files, but you will certainly have to modify your `web.config`, to point to the actuel path of the `mdf` file (`c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MY_SITE\AppData\MYDATABASE.mdf`).

Note: Also, the IIS User account should have the right to write the database; so the folder `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MY_SITE\AppData\` should have its security modified accordingly (right click, `Properties / Security`) to add the IIS User (as this is the account that should run the Web Site).